# Session help, with store and display on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session, gridview

How do I create one session with a list? Can one session contain many attributes? After create how to create on a gridview

```
if (Session["Cart"] == null)
{
   Session["Cart"] = new List<string>() { Id };
   var name = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
   name.Add(lblName.Text);
   var Qty = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
   Qty.Add(txtAddtoCart.Text);
   var Price = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
   Price.Add(lblPrice.Text);

   if (lblProductStates.Visible == true)
   {
      var Promotion = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
      Promotion.Add(lblProductStates.Text);
   }
}

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="BasketData" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" >
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly store `List` in `session` :-

for example :-

```
List<string> lt=new List<string>();
lt.Add("first");
```

Then store it in session:-

```
Session["Cart"]=lt;
```

When you want to retrieve data from session(on same or another page), you can do like this :-

```
List<string> lst=(List<string>)Session["cart"];
```

and Now finally bind it to gridview:-

```
GridView1.DataSource = lst;// Note gridview1 is your gridview ID
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok i get it thx u
List<string> cart = new List<string>();
                    cart.Add(Id);
                    cart.Add(lblName.Text);
                    cart.Add(txtAddtoCart.Text);
                    cart.Add(lblPrice.Text);
                    if (lblProductStates.Visible == true)
                    {
                        cart.Add(lblProductStates.Text);
                    }
                    Session["Cart"] = cart;

how about retrieve on other page? show at gridview?